# how does browser know it needs to execute callback when receiving cross domain JSONP

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, jquery-callback

when i am doing a cross domain AJAX , how is the returned resource (callback returned around JSON) result in the callback method in the client being executed.

is this feature (execution of callback) programmed into the AJAX client or is this part of the browser which upon receiving the wrapped data e.g. clientCallBack('json_data') from server trigger clientCallBack and passes it 'json_data'

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of the browser. JSONP is just regular javascript, there is nothing special about it. When a JSONP script is loaded, the server wraps the response in the callback function (for example, clientCallback('json_data')). The script containing this code is appended to the page's DOM as a script tag, which then forces the code inside the script to execute.